# Laravel 5.2 testing always returning 404

Tags: laravel, testing, http-status-code-404

guys,

I'm having this issue to create my firsts tests on my project. I already try almost everything, search in forums, but I can't resolve this problem. Every page that I try to access using get in my test is always returning 404.

```
public function testExample()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();
    $this->actingAs($user)->get('/book-original');
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) FileTest::testExample Expected status code 200, got 404.

I'm using a separeted .*env.testing* file, but try to setup my .*env* file same as the testing, in case the Laravel is ignoring the testing and reading the main one, but the result is the same.

I try to use the **$baseUrl** and *.env*'s **APP_URL** with http://localhost and my IP and try to use the return value from **php artisan serve** command, in my case, http://localhost:8000, but in both cases the error persists.

Important: I used **php artisan config:cache** every time I changed the configs.

I'm already lost. Has someone a hint to help here?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you show the `routes/web.php` file?

Comment: Also, is the url only returning 404 during tests or when you try to access it via the browser as well?

Comment: Only in tests. The project works perfectly via browser.

Comment: It's really hard to tell just like this. You need to provide more information. And have you tried doing `route('name-of-your-route')` instead of hardcoding the path?